# What does IP aliasing do?

Tags: ip-aliasing

Can someone explain IP aliasing, for example this command: `sudo ip addr add 8.8.8.8/32 dev lo`.

I've read online about it but it doesn't make much sense.

Is this a way to make names such as http://localhost resolved by 8.8.8.8?

How does it relate to the physical NIC and why is it primarily used?

**Edit**: Practically, http://localhost and http://8.8.8.8 result in the same page when I run a simple server on my machine. Makes sense, so the IP addresses 127.0.0.1 and 8.8.8.8 refer to the same machine, this one.

Thanks.

Comment: No, IP aliasing means "multiple IP addresses on an interface for the purposes of connecting to the same network or multiple networks".

Comment: @GregAskew Right, that's the definition but it's as informative is saying 'water is wet' to describe the molecular composition of water. What is it used for?

Comment: What is a feature introduced in 1995 for? Nostalgia and homework research mostly. "obsolete way to manage multiple IP-addresses/masks per interface" https://docs.kernel.org/networking/alias.html

Comment: First introduced in Windows in Windows NT 3.51, along with persistent routes.

Comment: What do you attempt to achieve?

Comment: Typical use case at the time was, web servers are expensive, and we need to host multiple sites on one server.

Comment: Linux will treat address 8.8.8.8 as loopback same as it treats 127.0.0.1.